# UTF-8 Accents not been well displayed in HTML email with PHPMailer

Tags: php, utf-8, phpmailer

I'm setup a PHPMailer PHP Form that send us the form to our Office 365 account. Im having issue with French accents displayed has "Ã©Ã©Ã© Ã Ã Ã  Ã§Ã§" accents like "éé àà çç".

PHP Form are encoded in UTF-8;
PHP Code are also encoded in UTF-8;

But the email received seems to not show the proper characters.

I have add theses settings and nothing has changed :

In the PHP file

```
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
```

Also

```
$mail->isHTML(true);     // Set email format to HTML
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
```

Php Sending Form Source Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
ini_set('startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);    

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'php/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'php/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'php/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$nom_compagnie = $_POST['nom_compagnie'];
$nom_complet = $_POST['nom_complet'];
$poste = $_POST['poste'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$commentaire = $_POST['commentaire'];
$from = $_POST['email'];

function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => 'PrivateKey',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

if (!$res['success']) {
    // What happens when the reCAPTCHA is not properly set up
    echo 'reCAPTCHA error: Check to make sure your keys match the registered domain and are in the correct locations. You may also want to doublecheck your code for typos or syntax errors.';

} else {
    // If CAPTCHA is successful...
    try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'EmailAccount';
    $mail->Password = 'Password';
    $mail->addReplyTo($from, $nom_complet);
    $mail->SetFrom ("Hidden", "Hidden");
    $mail->addCC ("Hidden", "Hidden");
    $mail->addAddress ('Hidden', 'Hidden);
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    //$mail->Debutoutput = fonction($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";}; //

    $mail->isHTML(true);     // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "FORMULAIRE CONTACT";
    $mail->Body    = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
    <title>Formulaire de Contact</title>
    ....
    </html>";
    $mail->AltBody = "";
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('email_form_contact-fr.html'));
    $mail->send();
    // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die(0);
    }
        header('Location: envoi_form_contact-success-fr.html');
}
```

?>

The email received has shown like this :

The H3 title in the email are shown

```
Vous avez reÃ§u un formulaire de contact via le site Web
```

It supposed to be written like this

```
Vous avez reçu un formulaire de contact via le site web
```

Accent "é" are also displayed has "Ã©".

I don't know where is the problem.

Any clue if my code are well programmed?

Thanks.

Comment: Resolved. Everything need to match UTF-8 (Form, PHP Language + Mail->Charset) need to match all the same format. Also my Outlook 2019 was shown bad language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$mail -> charSet = "UTF-8";
```

with

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Stéphane. [This page](https://i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html) describes the symptom you are seeing; one character turning into two means that your data is in UTF-8, but is being displayed using an 8-bit character set. Generally speaking, PHPMailer gets this right, so you need to figure out where you are going wrong.

If you use `SMTPDebug = 2` you will be able to see the message being sent (use a really short message body like `é` that is guaranteed to *only* work in UTF-8).

Make sure that the encoding of the script file itself is also UTF-8 - putting an emoji in it is a good way of being sure that it is.

The problem with diagnosing this is that you'll find your OS interferes - things like copying to the clipboard are likely to alter encodings - so the way to deal with it is to use a hex dump function that lets you inspect the actual byte values. French is one of the easier ones to look at because nearly all characters will be regular single-byte ASCII-compatible characters, and accented characters will be easier to spot. In PHP the [`bin2hex()`](https://php.net/bin2hex) function will do this.

You have 2 typos: `Debutoutput` should be `Debugoutput` and `fonction` should be `function` - and that is a good place to dump hex data from:

```
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo $str, "\n", bin2hex($str), "\n";};
```

Here's an example:

```
echo 'abc ', bin2hex('abc');
```

which will produce `abc 616263`; each input char results in 2 hex digits (1 byte) of output. If your input is `abé` and your charset is ISO-8859-1, it will come out as `abé 6162e9`, because é in that charset is `e9` (in hex). The *same* string in UTF-8 would come out as `abé 6162c3a9`, because é in UTF8 is `c3a9` - **two** bytes, not just one. Inspecting the characters like this allows you to be absolutely certain what character set the data is in - just looking at it is not good enough!

So, while I can't tell exactly where your problem is, hopefully you have some better ideas of how to diagnose it.